# QEMU: cannot run commands with non-root user

Tags: linux, sudo, kvm, qemu, libvirt

when I try to run any `qemu-system-x86_64` command, even `--help`, nothing happens (I check `ps` and there is nothing running in the background). As soon as I run the command with `sudo`, everything works. My user is already a member of the `kvm` group, the `kvm` group has rw permissions to `/dev/kvm`.I'm also a member of the `libvirt` group. Also, because I use [virsh](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libvirt), I have this variable already in place `LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI=qemu:///system`. What am I missing?

PS.: I'm trying to run `qemu` commands directly, not `libvirt`'s `virsh` commands.

Comment: What OS are you running? On my Mint 19.2 system, the only groups I got added to during installation were the *libvirt* ones.

Comment: I'm already a member of libvirt and kvm groups

Comment: sorry, but I can't replicate this. As far as I can see, your setup is exactly like mine, and I have none of these issues. Maybe a reinstall would fix it.

Comment: I tried reinstalling but it didn't help. I guess I will sudo it and move on. Thanks anyway.